# In flutter I am using AlertDialog, which has 2 action buttons Ok and Cancel, on click on Ok , I want to go to new screen, and end the current screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () { 
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, TyreScreen.id);
                      },
                      child: Text('Ok'),
                    ),
```

After it is pushed , end the current screen,please Help, I want to go to new screen, and end the current screen ??

Answer (score 2):

Try to do `Navigator.pushReplacement(context, newRoute);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () { 
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                child: Text('Cancel'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, TyreScreen.id).then((value) => Navigator.pop(context));
                  },
                  child: Text('Ok'),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call navigator pop twice, one for the dialog and one for the current screen.

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); //Will close the dialog
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); //Will close the current screen
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, TyreScreen.id); //Will push a new screen
  },
  child: Text('Ok'),
),
```

Comment: Well, your answer is partially correct..but not an efficient way..you can use `pushReplacement` instead of `pop` and then `push`..